# calling secondary function with datepicker in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to successfully close a modal when a date is selected from the react native datepicker componenet I have. I currently set the state of a variable to the date when it's selected like so:

```
onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({birthday: date})}}
```

However, I have a function `this.toggleModal()` that works on its own but I want to hit this function with the onDateChange as well but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried `onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({birthday: date})} => this.toggleModal()}` but it errors out.

How can I compound these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `toggleModal` along with `setState`, just place each in the callback:

```
onDateChange={(date) => {
                this.setState({birthday: date});
                this.toggleModal();
               }
              }
```

If you want to wait until setState is finished, you can furnish it with a callback as well:

```
this.setState({birthday: date}, this.toggleModal())};
```